# What is wrong with my try except? I'm not getting either print, nor an error

Tags: python, automation, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Very new to python and automation.
Our website has a counter at the top of the page to count down the days until Friday. It contains the number, and then the text - days until #friday (except for friday, which has no number, and displays It's #friday!)

My code for friday is working.

```
elif datetime.datetime.today().weekday() == 4:
countdown_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("friday-text").text
try:
    if countdown_text == "IT'S #FRIDAY":
        print("Friday Counter is correct. It's Friday.")
except:
    print("Friday Counter is incorrect")
```

My issue seems to be tying the number and text together. Here is what I have.

```
if datetime.datetime.today().weekday() == 0:
countdown_text = driver.find_element_by_class_name("friday-text").text
countdown_number  = driver.find_element_by_class_name("count")
try:
    if countdown_text == "DAYS UNTIL #FRIDAY" and countdown_number == 4:
        print("Friday Counter is correct. It's Monday - unfortunately.")
except:
    print("Friday Counter is incorrect.")
```

I currently get no output, nor error for today.

Comment: Are you trying to use `try .. except` instead of an `else` clause? And if so, why? No exception is raised by checking the value of those two variables against a string literal, and apparently that aren't their values either, so neither message gets printed.

Comment: I was using try...except only because I don't know any better. I got the print to work by changing the if to an assert based on another user's answer that seems to have been removed- but I can make them all if else statements if it gets me the same result.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this..

Key points:

- we first have a function to return today as an int
- we then check "if not friday, print how many days until friday"
- days_until_friday is a function that does basic math of friday (4) - today (1 if it's a tuesday)
- today_with_types is a way of getting named days from numbers using built in standard libs, no need to create a dict or a map. I say types because datetime is a an object on which we can do formatting and date time transformations/math with time delta.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def today_is():
  """
  this returns a single int of what is today
  0 = monday, 1 = tues, 2 = wed, 3 = thur
  you can test what happens on different days by changing return 1 or return 4
  """
  return datetime.today().weekday()

if today_is() != 4:

  def days_until_friday():
    countdown_days = 4 - today_is()
    return countdown_days

  today_with_types = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=today_is())

  print("mate, today is", today_with_types.strftime("%A"), "we got", days_until_friday(), "to go" )

else:
  countdown_text = "mate you made it, it's friday!!"
  print(countdown_text)
```

ooof, forgot/take it for granted: the imports, import only what you need, or name your imports, on the internets you will find examples of people using `datetime.datetime` vs `datetime` vs `dt` if you import `datetime.datetime` you gotta use that long name always.
If you import `datetime from datetime` then you can use `datetime` without the `datetime.` .
You can also name your imports... pay attention which function or class you import

named import example 1

```
from datetime import datetime as daybanana
print("HAHHAHAHAHAHAHA", daybanana.now())
```

example 2

```
import datetime as dt
print("HAHHAHAHAHAHAHA", dt.datetime.now())
```

Comment: this is very helpful - especially the importing names. Excuse me if I'm mistaken as I am new, but it seems what you have given is helpful if I was building the counter element if I understand it correctly. The element has been built and is on the page. Currently I'm trying to verify that the element is there and the text is correct. Here's what I now have, and I'm getting the print message that the day is incorrect for Monday (it is monday so I'm not sure why i'm getting that.)

Answer (score 0):

What you see above is a `if, else` job.
`try/except` is very very good, but I did not use it.
I chose not to use try/except, because I consider it the "next level" in complexity.

```
from datetime import datetime
import sys
def tell_time():
    print(datetime.now())
    
try:
    tell_time()
except Exception as e:
    print(
        "Error on line {}".format(sys.exc_info()[-1].tb_lineno),
        type(e).__name__,
        e,
    )
```

In example here:

1. we split our work in small functions
2. wen use *try* to *try* to run the code and *except* if the `tell_time()` function did not exit correctly.
3. If the *try* fails to run the code, you could make *except* run another function, AND log to file, or do nothing (it's your code your immagination).
4. Try adding some bad code inside `tell_time()` function, try to break `tell_time()` and run the code, see how it returns what is in the exception?
5. you could write execeptions for every failure, or even use the exception as an if/else but that is more typing, and more things to get correct before you see your code work (3 days to Friday!).